# What's a simple alternative to system("CLS")?

Tags: c++

After reading why `system()` is evil, I decided to not use features like `system("CLS")` and `system("PAUSE")`. Are there any easy alternatives that aren't OS dependent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard C++11 alternative to the Windows specific `system("CLS")` since C++11 does not know about screens.  However, consider using GNU [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) or [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) (both work on Linux, and have Windows variants [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm)). See also [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways:

Creating a function:

```
void ClearScreen()
{
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        printf( "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" );
}
```

This simply creates a function that displays 100 new lines. Slow, pathetic, but it works.

Also the only other non-OS dependent way to not use `system("cls")` would be working with [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) and [PDCurses](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/), although they can be overkill for smaller projects.

NCurses works for Unix and Linux and other POSIX systems, and PDCurses works for DOS, Windows, OS/2, and some other random systems.

Comment: `<conio.h>` is Windows specific. It does not exist on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, there is no portable way of "clearing" the screen. There however a portable way of "emulating" Windows' `system("pause")`, namely

```
std::cin.get(); // waits for ENTER
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't have one for system("CLS"). But you can use Sleep(int) function. It isn't as set up as the system("PAUSE") but you can set up the rest. The function pauses the program for as long as you like. Its parameter is an integer and according to its value the program sleeps. It is based on milliseconds. so Sleep(1000) would pause the program for 1000 milliseconds or 1 second because 1000 ms = 1 s.

```
 #include "iostream" // for the cout

 #include "windows.h" // for the Sleep() function

 using namespace std;

int main(){

cout << "hello" << endl;

Sleep(6000); // pauses program or puts it to 'sleep' for 6000 ms or 6 s


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why Ricky, would you care to explain?