# I have a problem with system() function when I use 'cls' command

Tags: c++, clion

I have a problem with `system("cls")` in cLion. I included `<cstdlib>`, but it doesn't work usually. It sometimes works as it wants, e.g. clear a few lines.

How can I fix it? Do I need another compiler or debbugger? Do I need to change something in the settings?

Comment: ***Do I need other compiler or debbugger?*** No

Comment: ***I have problem with system("cls") in cLion in C++. I included , but it doesn't work usually.*** Using `system("cls")` is not really the best approach. You may want to use `ncurses` and avoid this. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563428/whats-a-simple-alternative-to-systemcls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563428/whats-a-simple-alternative-to-systemcls)

Comment: "*but it doesn't work usually*" - what does that mean *exactly*? What are you expecting it to do, and what does it do (or not do) instead? Please be more specific.

Comment: Thank u I find that clion compiler does not have implementation of system function with cls command  yet so it doesn't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.